# How to load the file use the GCS path without IOError?

Tags: python, nlp, google-cloud-storage

I have met some problem when I run the XLNet code on Google Cloud TPU. When I choose the `gs://{model_path}/...` as the model path, it turns out the `IOError`.

Like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_classifier.py", line 903, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "run_classifier.py", line 722, in main
    sp.Load(FLAGS.spiece_model_file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sentencepiece.py", line 118, in Load
    return _sentencepiece.SentencePieceProcessor_Load(self, filename)
IOError: Not found: "gs://ykproject/pre-trained/xlnet_cased_L-24_H-1024_A-16/spiece.model": No such file or directory Error #2
```

The original code is:

```
sp = spm.SentencePieceProcessor()
sp.Load(FLAGS.spiece_model_file)
```

I tried to find out the reason. So I decided to load the GCS file in my Python file:

```
f = open("gs://ykproject/test.txt". "r")
```

The error is still presented:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs://ykproject/test.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems like you are trying to access the object files like they were on the machine's file system. To access objects on Cloud Storage (through Python) you'll need to instantiate the client, access to the specific bucket and get the object's data:

```
# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import storage

# Instantiates a client
storage_client = storage.Client()

# Instantiates the bucket
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)

# Instantiates the object
blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)

# Optionally download the object into your file system
blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)
```

You can find more information about downloading Cloud Storage objects [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-python)

Also, be sure your Cloud TPU service account has access to the Cloud Storage, if it doesn't, you can update the permissions using the "gsutil" CLI tool. Like this (for reading):

```
gsutil acl ch -u [SERVICE_ACCOUNT]:READER gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
```

Or like this (for writing):

```
gsutil acl ch -u [SERVICE_ACCOUNT]:WRITER gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
```

For information about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/storage-buckets).